Possible to create temp file without write back on close?
I'm trying to use a temp file with a pattern of "write then read". The size would exceed memory limit so decided to put it in local disk, while still benefiting from the speed enchancements via page cache.
However, I found when the program exits, a lot of writes to disk (write back) would occur and ate up the disk bandwidth. Is it possible to tell the OS to "skip writing back since I won't use it anymore"?

Does this happen even if you remove the file? I mean if the program is well written then it will open the file just once and it won't expect the pathname to exist later; so you can unlink the file before the program exits and the program will still use it. When the program exits, it closes the file and the OS knows the data can be truly removed from the filesystem. I did not test this, but maybe Linux is smart enough not to dump the cache in vain to an already deleted file no longer in use. Can you test this scenario with your program?

"I won't use it anymore" - So discard what you wrote by truncating the file to zero size. See https://superuser.com/questions/881777/what-happens-when-i-truncate-a-file-that-is-in-use
